# How to view finalized render PNG with shadow catcher when scene denoise is turned on?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shadows

What lies behind this picture of a dolphin is a mesh set to be a shadow catcher, so it can effectively product an image floating in space.
I understand that in Blender 3 the shadow catcher function seems a little different than earlier versions. Is it rendering in a separate layer? Because I only see one.

Under "combined", it has a "ShadowCatcher" layer.

I notice that when I turn off the Denoise option, the shadow appears in the render.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you see the *Shadow Catcher* pass in the render window's dropdown menu under *Combined* this means you have the *Shadow Catcher* pass enabled, which you find at *View Layer Properties* > *Passes* > *Light* > *Other*.

[image: shadow catcher pass]

In this case, the *Shadow Catcher* will not be showing directly in the render but is a separate pass which you can use in the *Compositor*. For example to make it brighter or darker or color it somehow, or use it as some kind of mask etc.

[image: shadow catcher pass in compositor]

If you do not want this and simply use the shadow catcher as before, disable the pass in the *View Layer Properties* and then the shadow will be fixed in the rendered image. In this case if you want to composite the shadow with a different brightness or color etc. you have to mask it out manually.

[image: compositor without shadow catcher pass]

Comment: I actually don't have "Shadow Catcher" enabled under View Layer... I see the shadow appear as the scene is rendering. But when I do turn on "Shadow Catcher",  no shadow appears at all during the render... or after. I've notcied that when i disable "Denoise" under Render Properties.

Comment: @Matthew Hmmm, that's strange. The _Shadow Catcher_ shouldn't be available under _Combined_ if the pass is not enabled... and I use _Denoise_ as well, but the shadow is there. Maybe you have to upload your file? Is it just this file or in a completely new created scene too? When you turn on _Shadow Catcher_ under _Passes_ it is normal that you don't see it while rendering or after. It is then only available as a separate pass (as I explained in my answer).

Comment: I simply want the shadow catcher to appear fixed in the final rendered image. I don't want to have any use of the compositor for this process.

Comment: When I disable "Denoise" under Scene, the shadow catcher appears in the render. So this has something to do with the denoise!

Comment: @Matthew But it shouldn't have to do with the _Denoise_ and in my latest and previous versions it didn't have an effect. That's why I already asked you to share your file to investigate it further because just from what you say I cannot reproduce this issue.